# How to pass multiple value with key to url using vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I have this attributes data

```
        for(var k = 0;k<this.form.fields.length;k++)
                    {
       
                        this.dynamic_fields.push({attribute_id:attributes[k].id,value: attributes[k].value})
                      
                    }

this.$router.push({ 
    path: '/api/search-temp',
    query:{
        attributes: this.encodedAttributes()                     
    }
});

    encodedAttributes() {
    const queryAttributes =this.dynamic_fields;
    if (queryAttributes) {
        return typeof queryAttributes !== "string"
            ? btoa(JSON.stringify(queryAttributes))
            : queryAttributes;
    }
    return "";
},
```

I have a attribute id and an attribute value so i want to pass this id and value to url so that i cab loop in my controller attributes array and get id and value :

```
localhost:8000..?attributes[]['attribute_id_1']=attributevalue1&attributes[]['attribute_id_2']=attributevalue2...
```

I'm redirecting like this :

```
 this.$router.push({ path: '/search-list',query:
                    {

                     
                    }
```

Issue is i want to pass this multidimentional array to url, anyother workaround for this is also highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may try is to json stringify and encode the object before passing it to the $route query

```js
function encodedAttributes() {
    const queryAttributes = this.$route.query.attributes;
    if (queryAttributes) {
        return typeof queryAttributes !== "string"
            ? btoa(JSON.stringify(this.$route.query.attributes))
            : queryAttributes;
    }
    return "";
}

function decodedAttributes() {
    const attributes = this.$route.query.attributes;
    if (typeof attributes === "string" && attributes.length) {
        return JSON.parse(atob(attributes));
    } else {
        return attributes;
    }        
}
```

And pass as query parameters to the route

```js
this.$router.push({ 
    path: '/search-list',
    query:{
        attributes: this.encodedAttributes()                     
    }
```

Then in the Controller you can decode the attributes value from request data to get the associated array

```php
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $request->attributes = is_array(
            $requestAttributes = json_decode(base64_decode($request->attributes), true)
        ) 
            ? $requestAttributes 
            : [];
        
        //Do other processing as needed
    }
}
```

Had used something similar in one of my projects can't get my hands on the code right now.

Probably you can use function to escape unicode characters in the `encodedAttributes` as well as `decodedAttributes` if need be

```js
function escapeUnicode(str){
    return str.replace(/[^\0-~]/g, c => '\\u' + ('000' + c.charCodeAt().toString(16)).slice(-4))
}

function encodedAttributes() {
    const queryAttributes = this.$route.query.attributes;
    if (queryAttributes) {
        return typeof queryAttributes !== "string"
            ? btoa(escapeUnicode(JSON.stringify(this.$route.query.attributes)))
            : queryAttributes;
    }
    return "";
}


function decodedAttributes() {
    const attributes = this.$route.query.attributes;
    if (typeof attributes === "string" && attributes.length) {
        return JSON.parse(atob(escapeUnicode(attributes)));
    } else {
        return attributes;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can u also specify in the answer how and in which format i will pass data to this.$route.query.attributes

Comment: That is what I have shown in the answer attributes can be a plain javascript object in vue component. What we are doing is converting the attributes object to JSON string and then encoding it before pushing it to this.$route

Comment: You can initialise `attributes` in the data function of the Vue component or a method. Then you can modify the signature of encodedAttributes as `function encodedAttributes(attributes = null){ const queryAttributes = attributes ? attributes || this.$route.query.attributes; //rest of the function declaration }`

Comment: I have tried but getting url like this attributes=`W3siYXR0cmlidXRlX2lkIjozLCJhdHRyaWJ1dGVfbmFtZSI6IlNlYXRzIiwidmFsdWUiOiI2In0seyJhdHRyaWJ1dGVfaWQiOjQsImF0dHJpYnV0ZV9uYW1lIjoiQ29sb3IiLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Ik90aGVyIn1d`, and not getting attribute, i have edited my code in my question can u please check what's the issue in the code

Comment: Yes it's an encoded string and you can easily decode it in your Laravel Controller. So what is the issue - that url has some nasty looking encoded string. It doesn't matter, in fact it's probably more preferable from security point of view

Comment: `$request->attributes = is_array($requestAttributes = json_decode(base64_decode($request->attributes), true)) ? $requestAttributes             : [];` in the controller and `dd($request->attributes)` giving me this error : **base64_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given**

Comment: `dd($request->input('attributes'))` whats the output. dd() first thing in the index method before any other statements

Comment: :its output is: `W3siYXR0cmlidXRlX2lkIjozLCJhdHRyaWJ1dGVfbmFtZSI6IlNlYXRzIiwidmFsdWUiOiI2In0seyJhdHRyaWJ1dGVfaWQiOjQsImF0dHJpYnV0ZV9uYW1lIjoiQ29sb3IiLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Ik90aGVyIn1d`

Comment: So it's definitely a string and not an object. `dd($request->attributes)` after the //Do something comment and see the output

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set a nested object to the query params, it's not possible... your route's query object must be a flat object.

Summarizing the only way for you to have something like this:

```
?attributes[]['attribute_id_1']=attributevalue1&attributes[]['attribute_id_2']=attributevalue2
```

Would be from a query object like this:

```js
query: {
  "attributes[]['attribute_id_1']": 'attributevalue1',
  "attributes[]['attribute_id_2']": 'attributevalue2',
}
```

You should flatten this multidimensional array into an simples object and use it as your query object.

Here is an example...
From this:

```js
const multiDimArr = [
  ['attribute_1', 'value1'],
  ['attribute_2', 'value2']
];
```

Into:

```
const myObject = {
  attribute_1: 'value1',
  attribute_2: 'value2'
}
```

A way to do so would be:

```js
const multiDimArr = [
  ['attribute_1', 'value1'],
  ['attribute_2', 'value2']
];

const myObject = {};

multiDimArr.forEach(arr => {
  myObject[arr[0]] = arr[1];
});
```

And then use the object as the query object, so your url will look like this:

```
?attribute_1=value1&attribute_2=value2
```